# Is it possible to emulate click inside a window? (Python+PyWinAuto)

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm writing a script with PyWinAuto. Is it possible to emulate click by coordinates inside one window?

(`click_input` only emulates click on screen, like in PyAutoGUI)

I tried to emulate click with `click_input` like `app.SomeChildWindow.click_input(coords=(15,15))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click by coordinates in window? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75674904/how-to-click-by-coordinates-in-window-python)

Comment: `click_input` method has parameter `absolute=False` to use relative coordinates. So the obvious answer is "it is possible". Please describe the exact problem in more details: with full traceback or step-by-step description.